# Paypal Dodirect without costing my client

Tags: php, paypal

I have coded first time paypal doDirect Method and it is working fine on sandbox mode but in order to make it live it gives the following error:

`[L_ERRORCODE0] => 10501`

[L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Invalid Configuration
[L_LONGMESSAGE0] => This transaction cannot be processed due to an invalid merchant configuration.
[L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error

So I then googled and found that my client needs to have a agreement which the Payments Pro costs $30 per month.

Is there another way to do it without it costing me this money?

Comment: [If you want the customers to pay without leaving your site, it's a $30 fee. If you bounce them to Paypal to pay, there's no fee.](https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/compare-business-products) Dodirect is afaik a "pay at your site service", which means $30.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Payments Advanced](https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/paypal-payments-advanced) for only $5/mo instead of $30/mo.

If you're a high volume I could get you setup with PayFlow (the new Payments Pro) without any monthly fee.  If you're doing $5k/mo or more in volume contact me directly and I can get you hooked up.